# How to show that $f(x; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha} \Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}$is a pdf?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, gamma-distribution

I have some problems trying to prove the following problem:

> A continuous random variable $X$ is said to have a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta > 0$ if it has a pdf given by:
>   $$f(x; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha} \Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}$$ if $x>0$, or $0$ otherwise.

Given that apparently this is a pdf by definition, I do not know how to prove it is a pdf. My guess is to check if I take the integration of the distribution the value should be $1$. Is this correct? Is that enough?

Comment: A function is a "PDF" (probability distribution function) if it the derivative of a "CDF" (cumulative probability function).  In particular that means a PDF is always positive, increasing, and its integral is 1.

Comment: Attention! PDF is NOT increasing! It is only non-negative and its integral must be 1. It can be easily seen: Integral of positive and increasing function could not be convergent.

Comment: Just look at the extension to the file name

Comment: @Yeah.. Hahahahaha, in an ideal world, yours could be an answer too. (+1).

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to be a typical definition of pdf for a basic probability course.
I got it from [this course site](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/97).
[image]

You will want to show that the function you have satisfies these conditions.

Comment: (+1) Actually, if the first two are satisfied, $f$ is a PDF. Then we can use $(3)$ to compute the probability that the random variable with this PDF is in the set $A$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. In fact, in $(3)$ it is stated in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)$ is a pdf if:

$f(x) \geq 0$ for all x. And,

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 1$

Comment: (+1) this is correct if the variable is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Indeed, I sacrificed generality for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing you a detailed solution since this is not your typical PDF problem.

$f \geq 0$; I'm leaving this to you.

As for showing that it integrates to $1$, the $\Gamma$ distribution is usually motivated by means of the $\Gamma$ **function**; by definition, 
$$\Gamma(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\text{ d}x\text{.}$$
Notice that showing
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}\text{ d}x=1$$
is equivalent to showing
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}\text{ d}x = \Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha}\text{.}$$
Well, 
$$\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\beta^{\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\text{ d}x\text{.}$$
This doesn't seem to lead me anywhere, so I'm going to try combining $x$ and $\beta$ into a single exponent by multiplying by $\beta/\beta$:
$$\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\beta}{\beta}\cdot\beta^{\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\text{ d}x = \int_{0}^{\infty}\beta\cdot\beta^{\alpha-1}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\text{ d}x = \beta\int_{0}^{\infty}(x\beta)^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\text{ d}x\text{.}$$
This seems to suggest the substitution $y = x\beta$, or $x = y/\beta$. Then $\text{d}y = \beta\text{ d}x$, or $\text{d}x = \dfrac{\text{d}y}{\beta}$, and (note the limits of integration don't change)
$$\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha} = \int_{0}^{\infty}y^{\alpha-1}e^{-y/\beta}\text{ d}y$$
(notice the $\beta$ cancel out). $y$ is just a dummy variable, so we have shown
$$\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha} = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}\text{ d}x$$
or
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}\text{ d}x=1$$
as desired.

Comment: directly : $\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x/\beta}dx = \beta^a \int_0^\infty y^{\alpha-1} e^{-y} dy = \Gamma(a) \beta^{\alpha}$ with the change of variable $y = x/\beta$